# How to handle ssl certificate in selenium IDE

Tags: ssl-certificate, selenium-ide

I am new to selenium. I am doing a cross browser testing in a tool called testingbot. When i run my site in their server through selenium ide the test runs till the url is entered in their VM. But after that there is a certificate error and the script is not run after that. The test fails.

Is there any way to handle ssl certificate or bypass it?

Comment: I believe you need to launch the browser with the SSL certificate exception already set to enable you to visit. I'd contact testingbot for more info: https://blog.testingbot.com/2012/01/02/selenium-sslhttps-support

Comment: Thanks. I think i got the point. IDE will not be able to detect element in VM. So ide will never be able to handle SSL certificate.

Comment: I don't think selenium (or the ide) will handle the SSL exception page without prior set up, no.